# Can induced-emf be divided?

Tags: electromagnetism

A conductor's area is reduced by half or possibly more. I calculated the induced-emf based on the original area unreduced, does it make sense to divide the induced-emf value to the reduction factor?

Say the area was reduced by half,therefore, diving the induced-emf value by /2?
I assume by reducing the area the induced-emf should be less?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, maybe not. It depends on the form of the magnetic field.

$$\mathcal{E}=-\frac{d}{dt}\int\mathbf{B}.d\mathbf{A} $$
If we can do this

$$\mathcal{E}=-\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{B}.\int d\mathbf{A} $$

then yes as the integral just gives the vector area. If you half the area, you half the flux passing through the loop. This condition is sufficient but not necessary.

Edit in response to comment about a square conductor:

Ok, since we're considering 2D conductors instead of wire loops of conductor let's forget Faraday's Law and consider the "work done" style equation. Let the square conductor lie in the $xy$ plane, the the magnetic field be $B$ pointing in the $z$ direction. Moving the conductor in the positive $x$ direction, speed $v$, the EMF "along a path $\Gamma$ between two points in the conductor (which connect to the circuit) is

$$ \mathcal{E}=\int_\Gamma\mathbf{v}\wedge\mathbf{B}.d\mathbf{l}=-vB\int_\Gamma\mathbf{\hat{y}}.d\mathbf{l}$$

Thus only paths that involve some change in $y$ coordinate note an $EMF$.

$$ \mathcal{E}=-vB\Delta y$$

The EMF depends on the magnetic force per unit charge acting on the conductor $vb$ and the path length. If we connect the circuit traversing only half the extent in the $y$ direction, the $EMF$ will be half compared to a circuit connecting across the full conductor. The current that flows through the circuit will then be halved as well.

Comment: Hm, well it's a magnetic field produced by an electromagnet how can I know the form and determine that? I assumed that "half" the flux would pass the area so it should be half the EMF, and the same concept applies if the conductor was moving and the field if "stationary" i/e motional EMF?

Comment: You could use Ampere's Law to calculate the form of the field. You may find the standard approximation, that the field inside a solenoid is constant everywhere, useful. Sometimes you can exploit the symmetry of the problem to make sense of halving.  If you gave some more details of the problem I could give more specific advice.

Comment: Well, Imagine this: A squared conductor connected to a circuit, that passes a magnetic field of $x$ $Tesla$, now there is induced $V$. Now, imagine that this squared conductor is sliced into smaller rectangles, sliced into smaller pieces but are still attached together, and you moved them again through the magnetic field should the induced $V$ be the same or higher or less? Since the area is sliced up into smaller parts. I assume it should be the same but current is divided.

Comment: Does the edit help answer your question?